# Flip boolean in Pygame (Main Menu)

Tags: python, oop, pygame

I'm currently working on a little 2d game in Pygame. Inside is a Player class which inherits from the Character class. The Player class has a movement function which handles keyboard inputs:

```
import pygame
import os
import sys
import time


pygame.init()

#window size
screen_width = 540
screen_height = 405

win = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))



#Village Background

#Village Background Overlay

#Background Music

#time for FPS management
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Character(object):
def __init__(self, x, y, character_width, character_height):
    self.x = x #character x position
    self.y = y #character y position
    self.character_width = character_width
    self.character_height = character_height
    self.velocity = 5 #character speed
    self.walk_count = 0
    self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28, 28)
```

Here is my player class:

```
class Player_Red(Character):
def __init__(self, x, y, character_width, character_height):
    super().__init__(x, y, character_width, character_height)
    self.red_char_right = False
    self.red_char_left = False
    self.red_char_down = False
    self.red_char_up = False
    self.latest_dir = "DOWN"
    self.pause = False

def draw(self, win):
    if not self.red_char_right and not self.red_char_left and not self.red_char_down and not self.red_char_up: #first display of character
        win.blit(red_char_walk_down[0], (self.x,self.y))
    if self.walk_count + 1 >= 27: #go to first image if no image to display left
        self.walk_count = 0
    if self.red_char_right: #display images red_char_right
        win.blit(red_char_walk_right[self.walk_count//3], (self.x,self.y))
        self.walk_count += 1
    elif self.red_char_left: #display images red_char_left
        win.blit(red_char_walk_left[self.walk_count//3], (self.x,self.y))
        self.walk_count += 1
    elif self.red_char_down: #display images red_char_down
        win.blit(red_char_walk_down[self.walk_count//3], (self.x,self.y))
        self.walk_count += 1
    elif self.red_char_up: #display images red_char_up
        win.blit(red_char_walk_up[self.walk_count//3], (self.x,self.y))
        self.walk_count += 1
    else: #display latest char image if no input
        if self.latest_dir == "right":
            win.blit(red_char_walk_right[0], (self.x,self.y))
        if self.latest_dir == "left":
            win.blit(red_char_walk_left[0], (self.x,self.y))
        if self.latest_dir == "down":
            win.blit(red_char_walk_down[0], (self.x,self.y))
        if self.latest_dir == "up":
            win.blit(red_char_walk_up[0], (self.x,self.y))
    self.hitbox = (self.x + 5, self.y + 1, 21, 30)

def movement(self, win):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() #keyboard input
    t = time.localtime()
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(current_time)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                self.pause = not self.pause

    if self.pause:
        return
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and self.x > 5:
        self.latest_dir = "left"
        if '{}: {}'.format(self.x, self.y) not in village_left_border: #handling a key
            self.x -= self.velocity
            self.red_char_right = False
            self.red_char_left = True
            self.red_char_down = False
            self.red_char_up = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_d] and self.x < screen_width-self.character_width:
        self.latest_dir = "right"
        if '{}: {}'.format(self.x, self.y) not in village_right_border: #handling d key
            self.x += self.velocity
            self.red_char_right = True
            self.red_char_left = False
            self.red_char_down = False
            self.red_char_up = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_w] and self.y > 5:
        self.latest_dir = "up"
        if '{}: {}'.format(self.x, self.y) not in village_upper_border: #handling w key
            self.y -= self.velocity
            self.red_char_right = False
            self.red_char_left = False
            self.red_char_down = False
            self.red_char_up = True

    elif keys[pygame.K_s] and self.y < screen_height-self.character_height:
        self.latest_dir = "down"
        if '{}: {}'.format(self.x, self.y) not in village_lower_border: #handling s key
            self.y += self.velocity
            self.red_char_right = False
            self.red_char_left = False
            self.red_char_down = True
            self.red_char_up = False

    else: #no key pressed
        self.red_char_right = False
        self.red_char_left = False
        self.red_char_down = False
        self.red_char_up = False
        self.walk_count = 0
```

For clarification it is a sprite of red from the pokemon series. Here is the rest of my code:

```
def redraw_game_window():
    #display background

    #display place

    #character
    Player.draw(win)

    #display background overlay
    win.blit(background_village_overlay, (0,0))

    pygame.display.update()


#checking if player is before a door
check_buildings()


Player = Player_Red(250, 150, 32, 32)


#borders of the map

#Sounds
def sound_handling()





#Mainloop
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(27) #FPS rate

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    #Player    
    Player.movement(win)

    #Sounds
    sound_handling()

    #Entering buildings
    check_buildings()

    #Update Window
    redraw_game_window()



#Mainloop End 
pygame.quit()
```

Above is most of my code. I left comments for things I've skipped too keep the code clear. The game runs with 27 frames per second. I've included a print statement in the movement method of the character class to see how often it looks for events (because I want to built in a main menu for which I need to handle the KEYUP - K_ESCAPE event). I want the code to check the KEYUP - K_ESCAPE event in every frame, however when I run the code I get the following:

17:29:20; 17:29:41; 17:30:37; 17:30:39; 17:30:50; 17:30:50;

I don't understand why the code does not enter the for event in pygame.event.get() loop once every tick meaning 27 times a second. It sometimes just doesn't enter it for 20seconds and sometimes twice a second. I've already looked what happens if I put the print statement outside the for loop and the movement method is called 27 times a second so it is just the for loop that doesn't run properly. Should any questions arise to my code, please ask.

Comment: You are performing pygame.event.get() twice in your main loop, as well as handling the pygame.key.get_pressed() separately on top of that. Once you check for Quit, once you check for Escape and the rest is other input. My suspicion is that this is not the intended approach. However, I think the problem is that if no events take place in a given frame, that for loop does not run, therefore the print does not trigger. As in it still checks regularly, but some of the time it has nothing to report. Next time you do your testing, hold down a keyboard button or something.

Comment: Yes you were right. It works no that I check the pygame.QUIT in the same loop as the pygame.K_ESCAPE event! Many thanks sir!

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to use `pygame.event.get()` instead of `pygame.key.get_pressed()`.

That way you can tell if the event is `KEYDOWN` or `KEYUP`. You could toggle your boolean on `KEYUP`, as that is a singular event that does not trigger multiple times.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            self.pause = not self.pause
```

EDIT: Adjusted the code from `if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:`.

Comment: Right, theoretically it works (first of all thanks). However, after I played around with the code I got the following error:

if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'
PS C:\Users\Pc>

Comment: I do not have a pygame install right now, so cannot verify, but I have seen this syntax many times: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/6891/pygame.KEYUP for example. Maybe a spelling mistake in your loop declaration?

Comment: @DavidA. The `event` object will not have the attribute `key` unless it's a key event. So you must check for `pygame.KEYUP` or `pygame.KEYDOWN` first. I would guess that you may have some indention error and check for the key before you check the type

Comment: @Ted Klein Bergman I suspected that and edited my answer to be a nested if. I documented it in the edit reason, but not in my answer. My original answer was using `event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE`. I am surprised, however, that it gets evaluated at all. Isn't it true in Python that if the first clause of an `and` evaluates to False, it does not evaluate the second clause?

Comment: Your first edit is also correct. I directed my response to David. I believe they made an error when trying to apply your answer, most likely an indention error.

Comment: @Ted Klein Bergman, I was concerned that my edit was misleading in the absence of a clarifying comment, since I was unable to verify that the original answer works well too. You bringing it up confirmed my expectations, but I am glad that it should still have worked.

Comment: Okay, after experimenting with the code it appears that the for loop is only executed irregularly. I've put a print statement including the current time into it to better demonstrate it:
21:40:52
21:40:53
21:40:53
21:40:55
21:41:01
21:41:02
as you can see sometimes the for loop just isn't executed (it is not linked to any conditional) and I really don't get why

Comment: It would help to see your code for this. Can you edit your original question to add this development?

Comment: I see that you updated the code. When do you run the `movement` procedure? Can you add another snippet for where it takes place in the code. Feel free to omit all other irrelevant code. I also do not understand your explanation of "irregular". Does the menu pop up when you press Escape? Can you update your question with expected behavior and actual behavior of the program?

Comment: I've edited my initial question and now included most of the code for context. I also tried to explain the problem that the event is only check irregularly a bit better!